# principal argument limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Given $z_n=2+i\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} (n=1,2...)$ Point out why $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \arg(z_n) = 0$.

Compare to $z_n=-2+i\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} (n=1,2...)$ where $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \arg(z_n)$ does not exist as $\lim_{2n\rightarrow \infty} \arg(z_n)=\pi$ and $\lim_{2n-1\rightarrow \infty} \arg(z_n)=-\pi$ (n=1,2...)

I solved this by using $\arg(z_n) = \arctan(\frac{y_n}{x_n})$ but I am unable to see why it approaches 0 for the first $z_n$ but not for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the $\arg$ function is non-analytic in non-positive real numbers i.e. *breaks* in them, since the definition of $\arg$, has a breakpoint at $\pi,-\pi$ as its range is $(-\pi,\pi]$. However it is analytic throughout $\Bbb C-\Bbb R^{\le 0}$. With $z_n=-2+{i(-1)^n\over n^2}$, you can find two sequences of complex numbers $$-2+{i\over 4n^2}$$ and $$-2-{i\over (2n+1)^2}$$ whose $\arg$s tend to $\pi$ and $-\pi$, while for the other one, you cannot.